# mac toolbar style

Tags: macos, cocoa, toolbar, tabbar, preference

Does anybody know how to make a toolbar which style is like top bar of "Xcode Organizer"?
Press different item ,different view will show down below.
It has toolbar style but tab bar function,Many mac apps' preference pane use it,I'm confused.
Can anybody help me please.
Thank you very much.
Plus this is a Mac Application

Comment: Your question is *very* vague... could you edit your question to add some screenshots or mock up something (in a drawing program) to show exactly what you are trying to do and what you want things to look like?  Right now, it sounds like you want to do some kind of custom NSViews (this is for MacOS and not iOS, yes??)

Comment: Thank you for your comment,I'm new to stack overflow,so I can't upload screenshots,sorry.

Comment: What I want is just like the "Organizer" window of Xcode,the toolbar has five toolbar items,press each item the status of it will become "selected".

Comment: That's just an ordinary `NSToolbar`. You need to use the delegate methods to manage selection of toolbar items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Toolbars/Toolbars.html) for `NSToolbar`. There are even some sample applications to get started with.

Good [overview](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2008/03/11/mac_secrets_preferences/) for making a better preferences window - see the link to a demo project on the second page of this article.